# Java Class Instantiation

Tags: java

I have a file, main.java, and several other files in the same package. Each file is something.class, and I would like to execute them, but I'm having problems locating how to instantiate the class from a something.java file, and then execute it. I am new to java, this is only the second program I've written so please be gentle.

One of the files I'm using is startmessage.java, and here is what I've tried:

`Object StartMessage = new StartMessage();`

I don't even know if that's correct. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are the problems you are having?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You can start with this tutorial :- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: The typical pattern for instantiating classes is: [type] [variable] = new [class name]();
StartMessage myStartMessageInstance = new StartMessage();

Comment: Ok, I have the declaration, now how do I use it to run the code? I'm used to vb.net where I just go "dim xx as new whatever"

Comment: Poor questions get poor answers no answers at all. Please post specific answerable questions from now onwards.

Comment: Ok, move to more basic tutorial: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Comment: Nevermind, I had public static void main(String[] args) in the class, I didn't know you had to change it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The class files are the compiled classes.
Source code for Java classes usually go in a file named after themselves.
For example, for your startmessage class, you would use StartMessage.java.

From another file, you can import the class, and then you can instantiate it an object of that type.

For example:

```
package example;
import StartMessage;
public class Example {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        StartMessage startMessage = new StartMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Case is important.

If your file really is called startmessage.java, and you've compiled it, and you want to create and instance of it, then try:

```
startmessage sm = new startmessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the Java class you'd like to utilize throughout your code:

```
package <package_name>

import <location_of_class>
```

Like so:

```
package michael;

import parent.child.*; //use any method with *
```

Useful link on imports and packages: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html

Answer (score 0):

In Java, files must be named exactly after the class they contain. In most cases this is a case-sensitive rule. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

That code segment would compile (assuming you have a StartMessage class with a default constructor), but it's not necessarily correct.  Generally, you will want to declare objects in the following fashion:

```
<type> <name> = new <type>(<args>);
```

By this design, your code segment would be more correct in the following form:

```
StartMessage message = new StartMessage();
```

However, because StartMessage is a subclass of Object, and variables can be named nearly anything, your original code compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

- To execute a precompiled java class (.class) it should have a main method to be executed 
  and it can be run using command java
  http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/
- For the second issue, please take a look at the following tutorial:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing your file name must be exactly as a class name. For e.g.: If you named the file `startmessage.java` then you class should look like this:

```
public class startmessage { }
```

But it is not the way to name java classes. The proper way is:

```
public class StartMessage {}
```

To instantiate a class you should do like this:

```
StartMessage message = new StartMessage();
```

If you do like this:

```
Object message = new StartMessage();
```

You won't be able to access methods of `StartMessage` class. The only methods will be available from the `Object` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your class by creating an instance (construct it). For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public void myMethod1() {System.out.println("Hello from method 1");}
  public void myMethod2() {System.out.println("Hello from method 2");}
}

public class Runner
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // declare variable of type MyClass
    MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();

    // now execute its methods
    myInstance.myMethod1();

    myInstance.myMethod2();
  }
}
```

This will produce output in the console:

```
Hello from method 1
Hello from method 2
```

As per your example in the question, you should use StartMessage instead of Object, e.g.

```
StartMessage myVariable = new StartMessage();
```